# I found a correlation between n^x and x! can anyone explain it?

Tags: factorial

[This is the example to numbers to the 3rd.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjkal.png)

[Here is the same thing just with numbers to the 4th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzdHS.png)

Well I was messing around with numbers I made this discovery, with the correlation between n^x and x!. What is the reason for this? Is it easily explainable?

In the sheets every column is found from the differences of two numbers in sequence in the last column

Comment: a polynomial of order $n$ will have a constant $n$:th derivative. the cubes are a polynomial of order 3 so if you differentiate three times you get constant. the differences you calculate are akin to differentiation in a way that you may not have learned yet.

Comment: To be honest, without further explanation I do not understand what the sheets contain.

Comment: @zoli I guess he calculates the differences of successive numbers from previous column..

Comment: What are you talking about? Those tables don't explain anything - at the very least you need to explain what the various columns represent...

Comment: 27-8 = 19, 19-7 = 12, etc

Comment: can you add more expanation and don't post things in links it is always better to type

Comment: Yes as @mathreadler said every column represents the differences of the last column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant keyword here is [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference). In general, if $f(n)$ is a sequence, we can construct from it a new sequence, the **forward difference**

$$(\Delta f)(n) = f(n+1) - f(n).$$

There is also a backward difference. For example, if $f(n) = n^2$, then

$$(\Delta f)(n) = (n + 1)^2 - n^2 = 2n + 1.$$

> **Exercise #1:** Show that if $f(n) = an^d + \dots $ is a polynomial of degree $d$ with leading coefficient $a$, then $(\Delta f)(n) = d an^{d-1} + \dots$ is a polynomial of degree $d - 1$ with leading coefficient $da$.
>
> **Exercise #2:** Use induction on exercise #1 to show that if $f(n) = n^d$, then $\Delta^d f$ (the result of taking the forward difference $d$ times) is the constant sequence with constant value $d!$.

If you've taken calculus this should remind you a lot of what happens when you differentiate polynomials. There are several more very nice things to say about finite differences but this is enough to explain your observation.

Answer (score 0):

The binomial theorem says

$$
(a+b)^x = a^x + xa^{x-1}b + \frac{x(x-1)}2 a^{x-2} b^2 + \frac{x(x-1)(x-2)} 6 a^{x-3} b^3 + \cdots.
$$
The differences in the column to the right of the one that lists values of $a^x$ are
$$
(a+1)^x - a^x = \left( a^x + x a^{x-1} + \frac{x(x-1)} 2a^{x-2} + \cdots \right) - a^x.
$$
Since $a^x$ cancels, you have $xa^{x-1}$ as the highest-degree term in the resulting polynomial function of $a.$

Then for the next row, for the same reason you get $x(x-1)x^{x-2}$ as the highest-degree term.

And next you get $x(x-1)(x-2)a^{x-3},$ and so on until finally you have $x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots 1 a^{x-x}.$